# How to index a table fields

Tags: mysql

i am developing a large table for messages inbox
A query like

> explain SELECT * FROM messages where (receptor='x1@yahoo.com' and sender='x2@yahoo.com') or (sender='x1@yahoo.com' and receptor='x2@yahoo.com') order by id desc LIMIT 10;

is very slow and cause to hang server
Please, let me to know how to index this table or change query to avoid this problem
Thanks

#### Table structure

```
mysql> DESCRIBE messages;                  
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| sender   | varchar(65)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| is_sdel  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| receptor | varchar(65)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| is_rdel  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| dtime    | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| title    | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| com      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| ipu      | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| flage    | tinyint(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| view     | tinyint(2)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Explain command result

```
 explain SELECT * FROM messages where (receptor='x1@yahoo.com' and sender='x2@yahoo.com') or (sender='x1@yahoo.com' and receptor='x2@yahoo.com') order by id desc LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys                                                                  | key                | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages | range | sender,receptor,receptor-id,receptor-view,sender-receptor-id,sender-is_sdel-id | sender-receptor-id | 134     | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: try out `explain SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages where (receptor='x1@yahoo.com' and sender='x2@yahoo.com') or (sender='x1@yahoo.com' and receptor='x2@yahoo.com')) x order by id desc LIMIT 10;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting my answer from comments:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM messages
  WHERE (receptor='x1@yahoo.com' and sender='x2@yahoo.com')
    or (sender='x1@yahoo.com' and receptor='x2@yahoo.com')
) x
order by id desc
LIMIT 10;
```

The problem you experienced was sorting very big table. This solution forces MySQL to first filter out messages in inner query, and then sort only these in outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Create index on WHERE column (receptor,sender)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sender_index
ON messages (sender)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX recever_index
ON messages (recever)
```